# Ideal layout in D3.Js for showing indoor navigation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on indoor navigation project and wanted to know what could be an ideal layout in case of D3.

I tried force layout but is not ideal because of overlapping edges and nodes.

Is there a layout where i just define node and links and have a path from one node to another?

my JSON file:

```
[
    {"source":"entry","target":"chocolate","value":20,"orientation":"down","x": 200, "y": 150},
    {"source":"chocolate","target":"bread","value":1,"orientation":"left","x": 140, "y": 300},
     {"source":"bread","target":"soap","value":1,"orientation":"right","x": 400, "y": 190}
]
```

my JS function:

```
$(function() {

var width = 1200,
    height = 800;
    var c10 = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height]);
d3.json("name_json.json", function(error, links) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var nodesByName = {};
  // Create nodes for each unique source and target.
  links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodeByName(link.source);
    link.target = nodeByName(link.target);
  });
  // Extract the array of nodes from the map by name.
  var nodes = d3.values(nodesByName);
  // Create the link lines.
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class","link")

    .attr("fill","none")
    .attr("stroke", "white");

  // Create the node circles.
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .attr("fill", function(d,i){ return c10(i); })
      .call(d3.drag);
  // Start the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();
  function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }


function nodeByName(name) {
    return nodesByName[name] || (nodesByName[name] = {name: name});
  }
  });
});
```

UPDATE: Added JSON and JS code

Right now I am using force layout but it gives me a layout which is not static as nodes can be dragged and could have overlapping edges.

I need a fixed position for my nodes. Then I can have edges and avoid overlapping.

One solution could be to have x and y coordinated defined in the JSON but I am not sure how to get them working.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you don't need a layout for this, as the geometry is given.

Comment: @lars-kotthoff could you elaborate a little?

Comment: The floor geometry is given and you want to plot point at particular locations, right? So you don't need a layout to compute the position of the points for you?

Comment: i know  what are my nodes and links. What I want is a static graph with fixed nodes and having edges. Can I have a graph with such  a configuration?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Are you saying that you want to find paths between the nodes automatically given a geometry? There's nothing in D3 that will do this.

Comment: what I mean is I want to just plot the edges and nodes give a simple information about them. Can I make the position of nodes static and have non-overlapping edges?

Comment: You'll have to explain in more detail what you want. What do you want to show? And no, there's nothing in the force layout to enforce non-overlapping edges.

Comment: i just updated the question

Comment: Well [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139) is an example of a static layout, but I don't see how all of this relates to a floor plan.

Comment: sorry for late comment on this. I am not sure how to go about a layout. Basically I want to fix my node positions. I looked at other possible options like Cytoscape or vis.js. Seems like D3 is not a way to go when you want a layout such as this.

Comment: If you know the positions, you don't know a layout. Just draw the nodes at the positions.